# How can I override a dynamic type's property in c#

Tags: c#, inheritance, dynamic, properties, polymorphism

I'm trying to override one property of my abstract class in the implementation class to be any type that I want for example, in my abastract class I have a property called Test1 and the type of it is dynamic, and in my subclass, I want to make this prop's type be like string instead of dynamic.

I have tried changing the scope, and a lot of other things but nothing works.

```
public abstract BaseClass<T> : where T : BaseClass<T>  {
    protected abstract dynamic Test1 { get; set; }

    public abstract T FetchAPI();
}

public class SubClass : BaseClass<SubClass> {
    protected override string Test1 { get; set;}

    public SubClass FetchAPI() {
        // Implementation here
        return this;
    }
}
```

The code above is what I want.

The code below is what works but now I can't access any property of field from Test1 property inside my abstract class.

```
    public abstract class BaseClass<T, U> where T : BaseClass<T, U>
    {
        protected abstract U Test1 { get; set; }
        public virtual T FetchAPI()
        {
            var type = typeof(U);

            Test1.Today.Date; // Throws error because Test1 doesn't contains definition for Today prop...

            return (T) this;
        }
    }

    public class SubClass : BaseClass<SubClass, DateTime>
    {
        protected override DateTime Test1 { get; set; }
        public override SubClass FetchAPI()
        {
            return this;
        }
    }
```